# Apply shift function group of rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create new column feature from curr_value feature. Here, I want get the value from previous current value, using `df.curr_value.shift(fill_value=-1)` I can get the previous value. How do apply shift to only unique 'uid' columns. For example, In below example, I want to apply shift to uniqie ID values.  `df[df['uid']==1].curr_value.shift(fill_value=-1)` Is there any other way in pandas so that I dont need to iterate unique uid values ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
events  = np.array([[1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 4], 
[1, 3, 3], 
[1, 3, 4], 
[2, 1, 4], 
[2, 2, 3]])
df=pd.DataFrame(data=events, columns=["uid", "eid", "curr_value"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can do it with `groupby`

```
df['pre'] = df.groupby('uid')['curr_value'].shift(fill_value=-1)
Out[5]: 
0   -1
1    1
2    4
3    3
4   -1
5    4
Name: curr_value, dtype: int32
```